# Best development practices when using JavaScript UI frameworks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, architecture, extjs4.2

I am not trying to build a framework here. I am investigating on the best practices/guide lines for developing an application using JavaScript UI frameworks namely, ExtJs MVC 4.2, Angular JS etc. Applications could be ranging from a personal book keeping, Maintaining Contacts to a very huge banking application. I believe there are some specifications to be followed when using individual JavaScript UI  frameworks. Did any one come across any interesting articles with guidelines for building a massive single page application?

NOTE: If the scope of the question is too big, please answer best practices for JavaScript part.

Comment: for ExtJS there are several Guides here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide

Answer (score 1):

Kind of tough to make a recommendation with such vague requirements.  Any of the frameworks can do this, so the question is which one do you like the best.  Lately for me if the application fits I will start with AngularJS.  It has it's own way of doing thing, but if you can live within it's limitations CRUD apps can be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Agreee with the CRUD part and REStfull service approach. Angular has memory leak issues. I have used both ExtJs and Angular as well in building applications for an organization. ExtJs has no memeory leaks and is a single page application, where as angular is tightly coupled with html pages and the binding thing is exceptional; but why memory leaks. I donot want to discuss about angular Js vs extJs. But are there any good practiece or ground rules when developing applications with Javascript UI frameworks. If angularJs has best practieces plz feel free to share the articles.

Comment: Because of it's popularity there are ton of good articles on Angular Developer.  But, here are a few links I find useful.   Project Structure - http://joshdmiller.github.io/ng-boilerplate/#/home.   UI Controls and Components - http://angular-ui.github.io/  (Angular UI Router can make things so easy and UI-Bootstrap is sublime).  I start projects with some variant of ng-boilerplate and use Angular-UI components for large sections of the UI.    Of course knowing how to write your own directives is the key to being very efficient in angular, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide is a good article and set of guidelines to follow.